# How to assign an instance of a class as a separate copy (not reference)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an array of `Employee's` called `m_AllEmployees`. `Employee` inherits from Unity's `ScriptableObject` class allowing me to create an asset in Unity. However, when I set the value of a field in `employee` it changes the value of the item in the array and therefore the asset in Unity. I need it to be copied so that they are separate and independent `Employees`.

`Employee employee = m_AllEmployees[index];`

Comment: You need DeepCopy/Clone. One way is to implement ICloneable then make DeepCopy (assign all propertoies from one to another) in Clone method. Other (hac) way will be to Serialize the object then Deserialize. you will get 2 separate instances.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you do a deep copy of an object in .NET (C# specifically)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-net-c-specifically)

Comment: Create a new `Employee` instance and assign all the properties from the other employee which you want to copy.

Comment: I can't serialize it because Unity's `ScriptableObject` is not serializable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) method for this. It will create a new object out of the object you passed to it and re-serialize all the fields.

Comment: Employee isn't a component for a `GameObject`, its a class that inherits `ScriptableObject` so that I can have assets in the project folder. I don't think you can instantiate a `ScriptableObject`.

Comment: You can. ScriptableObject derives from UnityEngine.Object (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScriptableObject.html) and that's what Instantiate method takes.

Comment: Will that create a new asset every time? I don't want to have extra assets or gameObjects.

Comment: No, it will not create a new asset or gameobject. It will create a new instance of ScriptableObject that will be a clone of the original one in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Implement clone/deepCopy method in Employee class and create a new instance by calling it.

```
Employee employee = m_AllEmployees[index].clone();
```

Comment: What do I actually put in the implementation?

Comment: @mr-matt: That depends entirely on what is in that class. For primitive types, string and properly done read-only structs, shallow cloning is enough. But for any reference types deep cloning might be nessesary: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Shallow_copy